# String var not keeping assignment in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I have a func that is supposed to return a string but it is returning the initial assignment of it instead of the of the value it is assigned within the func.

Code for the function:

```
    func labelToUser () -> String
{
    var userName: String = ""
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler{(connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else
        {
            userName = result.valueForKey("name") as! String

        }
    }


    return userName
}
```

The return statement at the end is returning the initial value of the string which is "". Instead of what I wrote in the "else" statement

Comment: If you add `print(userName)` within the brackets above the return what is the result?

Comment: Are you sure that the error isn't being printed to the console?

Comment: You need to learn about asynchronous calls.

Comment: Adding `print (userName)` prints out the user name in the console.
No errors in console.

Comment: Take rmaddy's advice, and read the question/answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691433/return-array-from-function-in-swift